# Show cursor location with CTRL problem on Ubuntu with Compiz

Tags: ubuntu, cursor, compiz

I am running Compiz on Ubuntu 10.10. I am fairly certain that Compiz provides the blue pulsating circle the surrounds the mouse pointer for a few seconds when the "CTRL" key is pressed. I recently used CompizConfig Settings Manager to change some window animations (open normal window: Domino, close normal window: Airplane). The animations apply correctly to my normal windows (like Chromium and gedit), but they also apply to that blue circle. Is there any specific window class I can use to exclude that blue circle from compiz when it provides the animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it to work. I found an open window with a class of "gsd-locate-pointer"; however, all my attempts to filter that out from the "normal" window filter filtered everything else out also, so in the end I changed the filter from:

```
((type=Normal | Unknown) | name=sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer | name=sun-awt-X11-XDialogPeer) & !(role=toolTipTip | role=qtooltip_label) & !(type=Normal & override_redirect=1) & !(name=gnome-screensaver))
```

to:

```
((type=Normal) | name=sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer | name=sun-awt-X11-XDialogPeer) & !(role=toolTipTip | role=qtooltip_label) & !(type=Normal & override_redirect=1) & !(name=gnome-screensaver))
```